# CSV file_get_contents sending PHP

Tags: php, csv, file-get-contents

I'm trying to send a .CSV file with PHP. The file is written to disk before it's sent but when I try to attach the file with file_get_contents(); the structure of the .CSV isn't preseved yet when try and send the file that's created before it's sent I get a resource id (#183) so how can i attach a file which the user can open as a .CSV file? I've made sure the mime type and headers are correct

EDIT

```
if(!file_exists(_PS_ORDERS_DIR_.$orderDate.'/'.$file_name.'.csv'))
{
        if($file = fopen (_PS_ORDERS_DIR_.$orderDate.'/'.$file_name.'.csv', 'x+'))
        {
        foreach ($list as $fields)
            {
                fputcsv($file, $fields);
            }


            $attachment['mime'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
            $attachment['content'] = file_get_contents(_PS_ORDERS_DIR_.$orderDate.'/'.$file_name.'.csv');
            $attachment['name'] = $order.'order';

    Mail::Send(1, 'order_conf', 'Order CSV Attachment', $success, 'dan.farr@gmail.com', CakeToppers, NULL, NULL, $attachment);
    return true;
        }
```

Comment: I don´t think the problem is `file_get_contents()`. How are you adding the file and sending the message?

Comment: I'm using Swift Mailer to send the e-mail. I remember I got this working a while ago using either file_get_contents() or fopen() or something like that but I've tried all combinations of using them with strings and resources but no luck. I know the CSV files are being created successfully because I can view them once they're created so I'm at a loss.

Comment: Plese post some code. It looks like you are using a variable that is an handler

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Swift Mailer, there is no need for `file_get_contents()`, you can just [attach the file directly](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/attaching-files).

From the Swift Mailer documentation:

```
//Create the attachment
// * Note that you can technically leave the content-type parameter out
$attachment = Swift_Attachment::fromPath('/path/to/image.jpg', 'image/jpeg');  

//Attach it to the message
$message->attach($attachment);
```

So for you that would be:

```
$attachment = Swift_Attachment::fromPath(_PS_ORDERS_DIR_.$orderDate.'/'.$file_name.'.csv', 'application/vnd.ms-excel');  

//Attach it to the message
$message->attach($attachment);
```